# Internal 500 error for linkedin login on a cake php site

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, linkedin-api

I have this website http://predikt.co/ which uses a Linkedin login. Some users face an internal 500 error when they try to login, not everyone sees this error. I tried to reproduce at my end, but I could only reproduce the error when I deleted my user_profile from the database, and tried to login again (I have to be logged into linkedin when I try that. if I logout from predikt.co and linkedin, and do a fresh login via linkedin the error is not seen). I read some similar posts which mention changes to htaccess, but couldnt find a solution for specifically my problem. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should check the logs. In most cases you can find more information in the logs when Cake throws an internal error.

Comment: I got this issue resolved. The error was caused due to empty fields being imported from linkedin and the database was not set to allow empty fields and no default values were set.